# accesing data in a dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so i have this code:

```
dic1 = { "data1":1, "data2":2, "data3":3}
dic2 = { "data1":4, "data2":5, "data3":6}
dic3 = { "data1":7, "data2":8, "data3":9}

data = [dic1, dic3, dic2]
```

how can i access the data in the dictionaries from a function if the input is the list?

so if i have a for:

```
for x in data:
  if x == "dic1":
    print dic1["data1"]
    print dic1["data2"]
  elif x == "dic2":
    print dic2["data1"]
and so on......
```

that will work but only because i know that those dictionaries exist but if another dictionary is created that method will obviously not work, so how can i do it.

Comment: `x` will be a `dict` in your example, not a `dict` key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop iterates over dictionaries, the second loop iterates over keys of dictionary considered by the first loop. Then you print every element:

```
for dictionary in data:
    for key in dictionary:
        print dictionary[key]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
for x in data:
    for k, v in x.items():
         print k, v
```

So the key here is to use the `items` method to access to the dictionary's elements.